# OpenModelica internal error reinit called with wrong args?

Tags: events, modelica, dymola, openmodelica, fmi

I'm writing a program that from an Functional Mock-Up Unit generates a complete Modelica model. It works just fine when I simulate the model in Dymola but in OpenModelica I get this error:

```
internal error reinit called with wrong args
```

I call `reinit(states, fmiGetContinuousStates(...));` where `fmiGetContinuousStates` returns with the new states of the model after an event has been triggered. Does somebody know what causes this problem?

Edit: 
Here is my model generated by my program. I now got an error `Error: type in operand to change must be simple type in component <NO COMPONENT>.`

```
within ;
package BouncingBall 
 model BouncingBall_fmu
public
  constant String fmuInstanceName = "BouncingBall";
  constant String dll_path = "C:\\P418-FMIModelicaImport\\trunk\\fmu_path\\win32\\BouncingBall\\Resources\\Library\\binaries\\win32\\BouncingBall.dll";
  constant String GUID = "{7d4fc270-b710-45bd-abb1-b1aefef341ea}";
  parameter Boolean fmuLogger = true;
  parameter Real e = 0.700000 "coefficient of restitution";
  parameter Real g = 9.810000 "gravity acceleration";
  parameter Real h_start = 1.000000;
  Real h(start = h_start) "height of ball";
  Real der_h_ "der(height of ball)";
  parameter Real v_start = 0.000000;
  Real v(start = v_start) "velocity of ball";
  Real der_v_ "der(velocity of ball)";
  parameter Boolean flying_start = true;
  Boolean flying(start = flying_start) "true, the ball is flying";
  parameter Boolean impact_start = false;
  Boolean impact(start = impact_start);
  parameter Real v_new_start = 0.000000;
  Real v_new(start = v_new_start);
protected
  parameter Integer fmuNumberOfContinuousStates = 2;
  Real states[fmuNumberOfContinuousStates](each fixed=false)
    "The continuous states";
  parameter Integer fmuNumberOfEventIndicators = 4;
  Real eventIndicators[fmuNumberOfEventIndicators](each fixed = false)
    "Event indicators";
  Boolean domain_change[fmuNumberOfEventIndicators](each start = false)
    "Checks zero-crossing";
  fmiFunctions.FMU fmu = fmiFunctions.FMU(fmuInstanceName, fmuLogger, dll_path, GUID);
  parameter Real initNextTime(fixed = false);
  parameter Real startTime =  0.000000;

  Boolean newStates(start = false);
  Real tNext(start = initNextTime);
  Boolean stepEvent;
  Real states_set;
  Real states_and_inputs_set = states_set;
  Real der_states[fmuNumberOfContinuousStates];
  Real tempStates[fmuNumberOfContinuousStates](each start = 0);
   package fmiFunctions
     class FMU
      extends ExternalObject;
      function constructor "Initialize fmu model"
       extends Modelica.Icons.Function;
       input String instanceName;
       input Boolean loggingOn;
       input String dll_path;
       input String GUID;
       output FMU fmu;
      external"C" fmu = fmiInstantiateModel_wrapper(instanceName, loggingOn, dll_path, GUID)
       annotation (Include="#include <BouncingBall_wrappers.c>");
      end constructor;

      function destructor "Release storage of fmu model"
       extends Modelica.Icons.Function;
       input FMU fmu;
      external"C" fmiFreeModelInstance_wrapper(fmu);
       annotation (Include="#include <BouncingBall_wrappers.c>");
      end destructor;
     end FMU;

     function fmiSetTime
      input FMU fmu;
      input Real t;
     external"C" fmiSetTime_wrapper(fmu, t)
       annotation (Include="#include <BouncingBall_wrappers.c>");
     end fmiSetTime;

     function fmiSetReal
      input FMU fmu;
      input Integer vr[:];
      input Real values[:];
      input Real inDummy;
      output Real outDummy = inDummy;
     external"C" fmiSetReal_wrapper(fmu, vr, size(vr,1), values)
       annotation (Include="#include <BouncingBall_wrappers.c>");
     end fmiSetReal;

     function fmiInitialize
      input FMU fmu;
      output Real t;
     external"C" t = fmiInitialize_wrapper(fmu)
       annotation (Include="#include <BouncingBall_wrappers.c>");
     end fmiInitialize;

     function fmiGetContinuousStates
      input FMU fmu;
      input Integer n;
      output Real x[n];
     external"C" fmiGetContinuousStates_wrapper(fmu, x, n)
       annotation (Include="#include <BouncingBall_wrappers.c>");
     end fmiGetContinuousStates;

     function fmiGetNominalContinuousStates
      input FMU fmu;
      input Integer n;
      output Real x_nom[n];
     external"C" fmiGetNominalContinuousStates_wrapper(fmu, x_nom, n)
       annotation (Include="#include <BouncingBall_wrappers.c>");
     end fmiGetNominalContinuousStates;

     function fmiGetReal
      input FMU fmu;
      input Integer vr[:];
      output Real values;
     external"C" fmiGetReal_wrapper(fmu, vr, size(vr,1), values)
       annotation (Include="#include <BouncingBall_wrappers.c>");
     end fmiGetReal;

     function fmiGetInteger
      input FMU fmu;
      input Integer vr[:];
      output Integer values;
     external"C" fmiGetInteger_wrapper(fmu, vr, size(vr,1), values);
       annotation (Include="#include <BouncingBall_wrappers.c>");
     end fmiGetInteger;

     function fmiSetInteger
      input FMU fmu;
      input Integer vr[:];
      input Integer values[:];
     external"C" fmiSetInteger_wrapper(fmu, vr, size(vr,1), values);
       annotation (Include="#include <BouncingBall_wrappers.c>");
     end fmiSetInteger;

     function fmiGetString
      input FMU fmu;
      input Integer vr[:];
      output String values;
     external"C" fmiGetString_wrapper(fmu, vr, size(vr,1), values);
       annotation (Include="#include <BouncingBall_wrappers.c>");
     end fmiGetString;

     function fmiSetString
      input FMU fmu;
      input Integer vr[:];
      input Integer values[:];
     external"C" fmiSetString_wrapper(fmu, vr, size(vr,1), values);
       annotation (Include="#include <BouncingBall_wrappers.c>");
     end fmiSetString;

     function fmiGetDerivatives
      input FMU fmu;
      input Integer n;
      output Real derivatives[n];
     external"C" fmiGetDerivatives_wrapper(fmu, derivatives, n)
       annotation (Include="#include <BouncingBall_wrappers.c>");
     end fmiGetDerivatives;

     function fmiSetContinuousStates
      input FMU fmu;
      input Real states[:];
      input Real inDummy;
      output Real outDummy = inDummy;
     external"C" fmiSetContinuousStates_wrapper(fmu, states, size(states,1))
       annotation (Include="#include <BouncingBall_wrappers.c>");
     end fmiSetContinuousStates;

     function fmiCompletedIntegratorStep
      input FMU fmu;
      input Real states_and_inputs_set;
      output Integer status;
     external"C" status = fmiCompletedIntegratorStep_wrapper(fmu)
       annotation (Include="#include <BouncingBall_wrappers.c>");
     end fmiCompletedIntegratorStep;

     function fmiEventUpdate
      input FMU fmu;
      output Real nextTime;
      output Boolean newStates;
     external"C" newStates = fmiEventUpdate_wrapper(fmu, nextTime)
       annotation (Include="#include <BouncingBall_wrappers.c>");
     end fmiEventUpdate;

     function fmiGetEventIndicators
      input FMU fmu;
      input Integer n;
      output Real eventIndicators[n];
     external"C" fmiGetEventIndicators_wrapper(fmu, eventIndicators, n)
       annotation (Include="#include <BouncingBall_wrappers.c>");
     end fmiGetEventIndicators;

     function fmiGetBoolean
      input FMU fmu;
      input Integer vr[:];
      output Boolean values;
     external"C" fmiGetBoolean_wrapper(fmu, vr, size(vr,1), values)
       annotation (Include="#include <BouncingBall_wrappers.c>");
     end fmiGetBoolean;

     function fmiSetBoolean
      input FMU fmu;
      input Integer vr[:];
      input Boolean values[:];
     external"C" fmiSetBoolean_wrapper(fmu, vr, size(vr,1), values)
       annotation (Include="#include <BouncingBall_wrappers.c>");
     end fmiSetBoolean;

     function fmiSetDebugLogging
      input FMU fmu;
      input Boolean loggingOn;
     external"C" fmiSetDebugLogging_wrapper(fmu, loggingOn)
       annotation (Include="#include <BouncingBall_wrappers.c>");
     end fmiSetDebugLogging;

     function fmiTerminate
      input FMU fmu;
     external"C" fmiTerminate_wrapper(fmu)
       annotation (Include="#include <BouncingBall_wrappers.c>");
     end fmiTerminate;
   end fmiFunctions;
 algorithm
  fmiFunctions.fmiSetTime(fmu, time);
  states_set := fmiFunctions.fmiSetContinuousStates(fmu, states, 1);
  der_states := fmiFunctions.fmiGetDerivatives(fmu, size(states,1));
  h := fmiFunctions.fmiGetReal(fmu, {33554432});
  der_h_ := fmiFunctions.fmiGetReal(fmu, {587202560});
  v := fmiFunctions.fmiGetReal(fmu, {33554433});
  der_v_ := fmiFunctions.fmiGetReal(fmu, {587202561});
  v_new := fmiFunctions.fmiGetReal(fmu, {637534210});
  flying :=fmiFunctions.fmiGetBoolean(fmu, {637534208});
  impact :=fmiFunctions.fmiGetBoolean(fmu, {637534209});
  eventIndicators := fmiFunctions.fmiGetEventIndicators(fmu, size(eventIndicators, 1));
  for i in 1:size(eventIndicators, 1) loop
   domain_change[i] := eventIndicators[i] > 0;
  end for;
  stepEvent := fmiFunctions.fmiCompletedIntegratorStep(fmu, states_and_inputs_set) > 0.5;

 equation
  der(states) = der_states;

  when cat(1, change(domain_change), {time >= pre(tNext) and pre(tNext) > 0, initial(), stepEvent}) then
   (tNext, newStates) = fmiFunctions.fmiEventUpdate(fmu);
  end when;

  when cat(1, change(domain_change), {time >= pre(tNext) and pre(tNext) > 0, initial(), stepEvent}) then
   if newStates then
     tempStates = fmiFunctions.fmiGetContinuousStates(fmu, fmuNumberOfContinuousStates);
   else
     tempStates = pre(tempStates);
   end if;
  end when;

  when cat(1, change(domain_change) and {newStates for i in 1:size(domain_change, 1)}, {time >= pre(tNext) and pre(tNext) > 0 and newStates, stepEvent and newStates}) then
    reinit(states, tempStates);
  end when;

 initial algorithm
  fmiFunctions.fmiSetReal(fmu, {16777216}, {e}, 1);
  fmiFunctions.fmiSetReal(fmu, {16777217}, {g}, 1);
  fmiFunctions.fmiSetReal(fmu, {33554432}, {h_start}, 1);
  fmiFunctions.fmiSetReal(fmu, {33554433}, {v_start}, 1);
  fmiFunctions.fmiSetBoolean(fmu, {637534208}, {flying_start});
  fmiFunctions.fmiSetBoolean(fmu, {637534209}, {impact_start});
  fmiFunctions.fmiSetReal(fmu, {637534210}, {v_new_start}, 1);
  fmiFunctions.fmiSetTime(fmu, startTime);
  initNextTime := fmiFunctions.fmiInitialize(fmu);
  states := fmiFunctions.fmiGetContinuousStates(fmu, size(states,1));
 end BouncingBall_fmu;


annotation (uses(Modelica(version="3.2")));
end BouncingBall;
```

Comment: Which version of fmu are you using? Which arguments are you providing? My understanding from the error message is that the arguments that are you providing to the fmu APIs are managed and modified by the simulation tool(Dymola or OpenModelica), and you get errors because these were modified in an way that these become incompatible to the FMU. My suggestion is to print out the arguments of this call in both tools in a log file in order to find out the source of this issue.

Comment: Turns out that it was a problem to use reinir-statements in algorithm sections. However, as of Modelica 3.3 it is legal. Now I get another problem, I will post my code in an answer.

Comment: Modelica Spec 3.2r2 (more recent than 3.3): "It [reinit] can only be applied in the body of a when clause in an equation section"